# Is it possible to create a local temp table in a stored procedure and continue using it after the stored procedure returns?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have the following code to demonstrate my question:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp2 (Id INT)
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('Test') IS NOT NULL 
   DROP PROCEDURE Test
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE Test
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 0 Id 
    INTO #tmp

    INSERT INTO #tmp2 (Id) 
    VALUES (1)
END
GO

EXEC Test

SELECT * FROM #tmp2
SELECT * FROM #tmp
```

Running the code yields the following messages:

```
(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

Msg 208, Level 16, State 0, Line 3
Invalid object name '#tmp'.
```

[image]

But the select from #tmp2 was successful:

[image]

The difference is that `#tmp` was created inside the stored procedure, but the `#tmp2` - not.

Is it possible to create a local temp table inside a stored procedure and continue using it after the stored procedure returns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot. As you've observed, you can access outer tables from an inner scope, but [unfortunately](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql#temporary-tables):

> A local temporary table created in a stored procedure is *dropped automatically when the stored procedure is finished*. The table can be referenced by any nested stored procedures executed by the stored procedure that created the table. The table cannot be referenced by the process that called the stored procedure that created the table.

(My *emphasis*)

My usual way of tackling this is as you already are - create the temp table (`#tmp2`) in the outer scope

Comment: @mark - I included the link in my answer. It's from a section of the `CREATE TABLE` documentation dedicated to temporary tables.

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of Temporary Tables, one Local Temporary Tables whose name starts with single # sign and other one is Global Temporary Tables whose name starts with two # signs: [more details](http://sqlhints.com/tag/temporary-table-scope/)

Local temp tables cannot be accessed outside of the procedure, but you can access the global temp tables.

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp2 (Id INT)
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('Test') IS NOT NULL DROP PROCEDURE Test
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE Test AS
BEGIN
  SELECT 0 Id INTO ##globalTemp
  INSERT INTO #tmp2 (Id) VALUES (1)
END
GO

EXEC Test
Go

SELECT * FROM #tmp2
SELECT * FROM ##globalTemp
```

The global temp table still exists...

[image]

Having said that, using global temp table like this is not a good practice.

Comment: Although this would solve the OP's question, it is strongly recommended that you don't use global temporary tables unless you absolutely need to, and that you are very careful in their use, because they are global they can cause concurrency issues.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Mathew, I added this note to my answer... I agree with you.

Comment: I will update the question. I am specifically interested in the local temp tables.